# How to upgrade Laravel 5.2 → 5.8

Tags: php

When upgrading laravel from 5.2 to 5.8, do I need to upgrade one by one each with 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5,6, 5.7, 5.8, and check each details of changes? Or can I go to 5.8 at once by Composer JSON upgrade?

I would like to know general upgrade method of Laravel 5.2 → 5.8?

Comment: While I have no deep experience with Laravel, virtually all package managed software frameworks work on the philosophy of a cumulative upgrade being the default. So I would recommend you just upgrade to [Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade) directly from 5.2 and all should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternative ways of upgrading Laravel to version 5.8:

1. Create new project with Laravel 5.8, and then install packages. Then move your all models and controller to your new project.
2. Upgrade Laravel one-by-one with versions 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5,6, 5.7 and 5.8 by following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275711/laravel-upgrade-issue-from-5-2-to-5-7/54275788#54275788).

Answer (score 0):

Best option is create the new laravel project when you upgrade you old version then stop some point so used new version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).